# Install MCR (MATLAB compiler) on EC2 instance

Tags: matlab, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

I have an EC2 instance set up and I am ssh into it through putty. Now I would like to install MCR which is MATLAB compiler runtime on this instance. I downloaded the .exe file on my machine but not sure what exactly is the code I should be running.

I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://pensieve.info/blog/2013/10/08/running-matlab-code-on-amazon-cloud/

But the problem is that tutorial is meant for a linux machine and I am working with windows.

Following is the link for MCR: http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/?refresh=true

I have been struggling with this for a long time and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are confused. You said `I am ssh into it through putty` and then you said `I am working with windows`. You don't connect to Windows instance via Putty. Instead, you need to use RDP. Please correct your post with correct information.

Comment: well [you could](http://www.frontiertown.co.uk/2013/10/ssh-amazon-ec2-windows-servers/) install an SSH daemon on the Windows instance, connect using PuTTY, and run an installer unattended from the command line... But I agree it's just easier to connect using RDP and just install stuff normally, especially if you don't need all that level of automation

Comment: Its not a windows instance. I meant my laptop has windows os. 

I created a custom AMI and then created an instance on AWS using that custom AMI.

Comment: @Amro, What you said is as good as going to Antarctica via Moon (pun intended).

Comment: @user2916628: you can only create standalone EXE programs using MATLAB Compiler from a Windows laptop, so you'll have to use a Windows instance and install a Windows-specific on it MCR if you want to run the compiled program on the cloud. Otherwise you'll have to run a Linux version of MATLAB locally and use the MATLAB Compiler from there...